# Java Threads, wrong counter

Tags: java, multithreading

I run below snippet and I got unexpected behaviour. Probably it is working in correct way, but I need to make it working in other way. Details below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TaskExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final PositionHolder holder = new PositionHolder();
    final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        holder.setPosition(i);
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                data.add(holder.getPosition());
            }
        };

        t.start();
        threads.add(t);
    }

    for (Thread thread : threads) {            
            thread.join();
        }

    for(int i : data){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}

class PositionHolder {

    int position = 0;

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
}
```

And I got result:

> 10 12 9 8 6 6 5 4 2 1 16 16 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 19

Why? I'd like to get:

> 1 2 3 4 ...... 20

Is there any options to do imporve this snippet?

Comment: You need to synchronize calls to your `data`.

Comment: How to do this? WHen I add:  <br/> public synchronized void run() {
                    data.add(holder.getPosition());
                } I got: 9
2
9
9
3
10
11
14
14
15
16
15
16
18
19
19
19
19
19
19

Comment: And if u want to have them "sorted" You need to synchronize running the threads, one after the other, becouse u can't know which 1 will get processor first.

Comment: There are many resources online that show how to synchronize low-level multiple threads against data - including a number of questions on stack overflow. Just google it.

Comment: use `Set` instead of `List` if you need it sorted.

Comment: @user3218114 wrong. `Set`s don't retain equal items, they don't sort per se (unless you're using a `TreeSet`).

Comment: @Mena - I think, his design is flawed, he will have to synchronize within the loop itself otherwise he might get *unpredictable output*.

Comment: @TheLostMind looks like it indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code ;)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ogr
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final PositionHolder holder = new PositionHolder();
        final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            holder.setPosition(i);
            Thread t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    data.add(holder.getPosition());
                }
            };

            t.start();
            t.join();
        }

        for (int i : data) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

class PositionHolder
{

    int position = 0;

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this will work, you will actually be blocking the *main* thread until `t` finishes. Also, this would prevent optimizations in loops.

Comment: Yes it will, since he wants an output like 
"1,2,3,4,...,20" he needs it to be launched one by one, becouse of we can't take all threads at once, and assure that they are going to be executed in order. Other way of doing it, is just sorting the output array ;)

Comment: It is working. Thanks. So if I have to run it one by one I don't need threads for it I guess?

Comment: So if I have to run it one by one I don't need threads for it I guess?

Comment: That's just my solution for demanded output. To maintain multi-thread, You need to change 
    public void run() {
                    data.add(holder.getPosition());
                }
Becouse your thread will add value to Your list, which is value in a exact moment of execution of thread (poor english). Let's say that u have 1 second intervals on increasing position, and u launch 3 threads in this time, 3 threads will have the same value.
P.S. Please let me know how to edit comment to achieve code block in comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee that the holder.getPosition() will get the same position values you set using holder.setPosition(i) as the getHolder call is part of a different thread and is called by multiple threads. This is because you are sharing the same PlaceHolder across all threads. If you want to get the output you desire, I would suggest using a different instance of PlaceHolder for each thread.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TaskExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         // Create new instance
         final PositionHolder holder = new PositionHolder(i);
         Thread t = new Thread() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 data.add(holder.getPosition());
             }
         };
     t.start();
     threads.add(t);

     for (Thread thread : threads) {            
         thread.join();
     }

     for(int i : data){
         System.out.println(i);
     }
}

class PositionHolder {
    private int position = 0;

    public PositionHolder(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee execution order of the thread without synchronization mechanism like `join()` (see code proposed by Fincio).

You are getting the same number several times because you are using the same `PositionHolder` object for all your thread, therefore, the variable `position` get modified by every thread you started. Trying to do the same with an Object instead of an int would probably got you a `ConcurrentAccessException`. To avoid this, each thread should have its own `PositionHolder` instance (like in code provided by Saket). But even with that, there is no guarantee about the order in which thread will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

programming using threads sometimes requires some tricks to make the threading efficient. Obviously it won't be as natural. for example check the following.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ogr{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<PositionHolder> holders=new ArrayList<PositionHolder>();
    final PositionHolder holder = new PositionHolder();
    final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                data.add(getSetPosition());
            }
        };
        holders.add(holder)
        t.start();

    }
    for (Thread thread : threads) {            
        thread.join();
    }

    SortByPosition(holders); //you can implement this easy by sorting arraylist by their positions

    for (int i : data) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}

class PositionHolder{

static int staticPosition=0;
int position = 0;

public int synchronized getSetPosition() {
       this.position = staticPosition++;
       return position;
}

 //  public void setPosition(int position) {
 //      this.position = position;
 //  }

public int getPosition() {
    return this.position;
}
}
```

Comment: @DariuszStachyra it would be great if you could actually edit the answer to exactly fit the requirement.

Comment: Modification are required only for my custom issue. Above code is working as expected.